# subprocess command execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

What is the best way to execute the below command in Python in a single line?

`echo $(readlink /sys/dev/block/$(mountpoint -d /))`

Tried using individual `os.system(cmd)` by separating - `"mountpoint -d /"` first and taking the output and appending to `"readlink /sys/dev/block/${0}".format(out.strip())` and doing an echo works. Tried using `subprocess` and `subprocess.Popen` and `subprocess.check_output` but it raises `raise CalledProcessError`

`cmd = "echo $(readlink /sys/dev/block/$(mountpoint -d /))"`

Comment: What exactly causes the CalledProcessError? Please include a traceback and/or other debugging information.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the subcommand separately. And you can use python methods to read the link:

```
import subprocess
import os

path = "/"
device = subprocess.run(["mountpoint", "-d", path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding="utf8").stdout.strip()

link = os.readlink("/sys/dev/block/" + device)
print(link)
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to use something like the following:

```
cmd = "bash -c 'echo $(readlink /sys/dev/block/$(mountpoint -d /))'"
```

echo doesn't substitute $() blocks, that's what your shell does, so you have to call the shell. os.system(cmd) should work then.

Comment: That's a [useless `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) so you will probably want to factor that out too.

Comment: `subprocess.run` with `shell=True` is generally superior to `os.system`, especially if you want Python to receive the output from the subprocess.